# Finding the nth item in a repeating list of fixed items

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have to determine the mathematical formula to calculate a particular repeating position in a series of numbers. The list of numbers repeats ad infinitum and I need to find the number every ***n*** numbers in this list. So I want to find the ***n***th item in a list of repeating ***y*** numbers.

For example, if my list has 7 digits (y=7) and I need every 5th item (n=5), how do I find that item?
The list would be like this (which I've grouped in fives for ease of viewing):

```
12345 67123 45671 23456 71234 56712 34567
```

I need to find in the first grouping number 5, then in the second grouping number 3, then 1 from the third group, then 6, then 4, then 2, then 7.

This needs to work for any number for ***y*** and ***n***. I usually use a modulus for finding ***n***th items, but only when the list keeps increasing in number and not resetting.

I'm trying to do this in Javascript or JQuery as it's a browser based problem, but I'm not very mathematical so I'm struggling to solve it.

Thanks!

---

**Edit**: I'm looking for a mathematical solution to this ideally but I'll explain a little more about the problem, but it may just add confusion. I have a list of items in a carousel arrangement. In my example there are 7 unique items (it could be any number), but the list in real terms is actually five times that size (nothing to do with the groups of 5 above) with four sets of duplicates that I create.

To give the illusion of scrolling to infinity, the list position is reset on the 'last' page (there are two pages in this example as items 1-7 span across the 5 item wide viewport). Those groups above represent pages as there are 5 items per page in my example. The duplicates provide the padding necessary to fill in any blank spaces that may occur when moving to the next page of items (page 2 for instance starts with 6 and 7 but then would be empty if it weren't for the duplicated 1,2 and 3). When the page goes past the last page (so if we try to go to page 3) then I reposition them further back in the list to page one, but offset so it looks like they are still going forwards forever.

This is why I can't use an array index and why it would be useful to have a mathematical solution. I realise there are carousels out there that do similar tasks to what I'm trying to achieve, but I have to use the one I've got!

Comment: Could you post your list, or a part thereof, as json? It's unclear what type of data it contains.

Comment: Will the grouped numbers always be separated by spaces?

Comment: There isn't really a list as such. In my example (it will change) I have one 'real' list of 7 items, 4 duplicates for padding on either side of the list and a sliding viewport of 5 items. I'm basically trying to predict when the page needs to move onto the next set of 5 items when the autotimer kicks off. Manually selecting next is fine, I've got all that working fine. I only have access to the active index of items 1 through 7. Hopefully I'm making sense!

Comment: The answer to my original question (how to calculate nth item in a repeating list) is (n*x)mod y where n represents the viewport size, y is the length of the list and x is the iteration. I still need to work this into my solution but this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just loop every 5 characters, like so:

```
var data = "12345671234567123456712345671234567";
var results = [];

for(var i = 4; i < data.length; i += 5){
    results.push(data[i]);
}

//results = [5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7]
```

If you want to use a variable `x = 5;` then your for loop would look like this:

```
for(var i = x - 1; i < data.length; i += x){...
```

There is no need to know `y`

Comment: Sorry, I never made it clear that the solution needs to be mathematical as I don't have my data in a list in that fashion and I'm not able to either.

Comment: @StuartRadley: Oh I see what you mean now. How long should the loop go on for? i.e. how many results do you want?

Answer (score 0):

If your input sequence doesn't terminate, then outputting every nth item will eventually produce its own repeating sequence. The period (length) of this repetition will be the lowest common multiple of the period of the input sequence (`y`) and the step size used for outputting its items (`x`).

If you want to output only the first repetition, then something like this should do the trick (untested):

```
var sequence = "1234567";
var x = 5;
var y = sequence.length;
var count = lcm(x, y);
var offset = 4;

var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i += x)
{
    j = (offset + i) % y;
    output.push(sequence[j]);
}
```

You should be able to find an algorithm for computing the LCM of two integers fairly easily.

Comment: This coule be useful. I'm looking into it just now. So given my sequence (which will always be 1 to N in increments of 1) I'm able to specify the group size (5) and total items (7) to find every fifth item?

Comment: @musefan Are you going to draw a conclusion from that?

Comment: When I use the above (with an LCM of 35 for this example) I get output 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc...

Comment: @musefan That's just as well; I think the sample size of 2 is a little small :-)

Comment: @StuartRadley: Apologies; see modified code. The step size for the loop should of course have been 5, not 1. I've also added `offset` to achieve the exact output you you were after.

Answer (score 0):

A purely mathematical definition? Err..

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + K For all n > 0.
T(1) = K // If user wants the first element in the series, you return the Kth element.
T(0) = 0 // If the user want's a non-existent element, they get 0.

Where K denotes the interval.
n denotes the desired term.
T() denotes the function that generates the list.

Lets assume we want every Kth element.

T(1) = T(0) + K = K
T(2) = T(1) + K = 2K
T(3) = T(2) + K = 3K

T(n) = nk. // This looks like a promising equation. Let's prove it:

So n is any n > 1. The next step in the equation is n+1, so we need to prove that

T(n + 1) = k(n + 1).
```

So let's have a go.

```
T(n+1) = T(N+1-1) + K.
T(n+1) = T(n) + K
Assume that T(n) = nk.

T(n+1) = nk + k
T(n+1) = k(n + 1).
```

And there is your proof, by induction, that `T(n) = nk`.

That is about as mathematical as you're gonna get on SO.

Nice simple recurrence relation that describes it quite well there.

Answer (score 0):

After your edit I make another solution;)

```
var n = 5, y = 7;


for (var i = 1; i<=y; i++) {
    var offset = ( i*y - (i-1)*n ) % y;
    var result = 0; 
    if (offset === n) {
        result = y;
    } else {
        result =  (n - offset) > 0 ? n - offset : offset;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

[5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7] in output.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/mcrLQ/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
function get(x, A, B) {
  var r = (x * A) % B;
  return r ? r : B;
}

var A = 5;
var B = 7;
var C = [];

for (var x = 1; x <= B; ++x) {
    C.push(get(x, A, B));
}

console.log(C);
```

**Result:** [5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7]

http://jsfiddle.net/xRFTD/

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = "12345 67123 45671 23456 71234 56712 34567";
var x = 5;
var y = 7;
var results = [];
var i = x - 1; // enumeration in string starts from zero

while ( i <= data.length){
    results.push(data[i]);
    i = i + x + 1;// +1 for spaces ignoring 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure the real data contains the spaces, I could be wrong though

Comment: I case of there are no spaces  `i = i+ x + 1;` should be replaced on  `i = i + x;`

Comment: No, the real data is annoying complicated and doesn't exist in a traditional way :D

Comment: Read your edit - got the problem - my solution is OK, but not for current problem.